# Error in second time execute application React Native

Tags: react-native, gradlew

I'm a difficulty to run my application in genymotion.
When a first time i run the commands `npx react-native start` and `npx react-native run-android`, my application works ok, but when i install libraries which i use in my project and follow the commands again the console show me a error, i tried uninstall the application from android emulator, ./gradlew clean but nothing to work.
My ambiance variable it's ok, because the application run in first time which execute.
Somebody can help? Please
Follow the error:

```
npx react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 956 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED
7 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 5 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not download material-1.1.0.aar (com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/material/material/1.1.0/material-1.1.0.aar'.
         > Read timed out

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 37s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not download material-1.1.0.aar (com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/material/material/1.1.0/material-1.1.0.aar'.
         > Read timed out

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 37s

    at makeError (/mnt/hd/www/react-native/projects/tutorial-projects/notas/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /mnt/hd/www/react-native/projects/tutorial-projects/notas/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/mnt/hd/www/react-native/projects/tutorial-projects/notas/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/mnt/hd/www/react-native/projects/tutorial-projects/notas/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:186:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Comment: What is an ambiance variable? 
It looks like one of your dependencies doesn't exist, try updating its version? `Could not download material-1.1.0.aar`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue.
I change my build.gradle file.
Before:

```
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
```

After:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
```